# use txt ids to build string

Tags: bash, shell

I want to extract ids from a text file and build a string for a curl request
I tried this

```
#!/bin/bash
for ids in `cat numbers.txt`
do
    echo "hi/$ids/oo"
done
echo "ALL DONE"
```

But this gives me the wrong output. It prints

```
/oo12341
/oo56z49
/oo60272347
/oo2347
/oo12312356
hi/124556616/oo
ALL DONE
```

instead of:

```
 hi/12341/oo
 hi/56z49/oo
 hi/60272347/oo
 hi/2347/oo
 hi/12312356/oo
 hi/124556616/oo
```

Comment: The file `numbers.txt` has DOS line endings.

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Quickfix: use `tr -d \\r < numbers.txt` instead of `cat numbers.txt`. Better long-term solution: Convert `numbers.txt` using `dos2unix` and fix the other problems in your script, see https://www.shellcheck.net/.